# Scala pattern match infers `Any` instead of an existential type, breaks type safety?

Tags: scala, types

I ran into a puzzling type inference problem with case classes. Here's a minimal example:

```
trait T[X]
case class Thing[A, B, X](a: A, f: A => B) extends T[X]

def hmm[X](t: T[X]) = t match {
  case Thing(a, f) => f("this really shouldn't typecheck")
}
```

Scala decides that `a: Any` and `f: Any => Any`, but that's inappropriate; they really ought to have types `a: SomeTypeA` and `f: SomeTypeA => SomeTypeB`, where `SomeTypeA` and `SomeTypeB` are unknown types.

Another way of saying this is that I think the hypothetical `Thing.unapply` method should look something like

```
def unapply[X](t: T[X]): Option[(A, A => B)] forSome { type A; type B } = {
  t match {
    case thing: Thing[_, _, X] => Some((thing.a, thing.f))
  }
}
```

This version correctly gives a type error at `f("this really shouldn't typecheck")`.

Does this seem like a bug in the compiler, or am I missing something?

Edit: This is on Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: Scala has to give `A` and `B` a type, so what type should it give them since you didn't specify what the types should be?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but the custom `unapply` method works correctly. The compiler keeps track of the fact that `a` and `f` have related types.

Comment: I agree with @Noah, without something to go on the compiler should default to Any. But I do see how this could be potentially dangerous.

Comment: @AlanO'Donnell Why do you infer that `Thing.unapply` should have the signature `def unapply[X](t: T[X])`. The compiler is auto generating an unapply that more closely matches `def unapply[A, B, X](t: Thing[A, B, X])`.

Comment: @Noah, ah, you're right, I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark Harrah pointed this out in the #scala channel on Freenode: yes, this is a bug.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6680