# Erroneous Scala code using polymorphic ADT type checks

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typechecking, algebraic-data-types

I'm doing some exercises to better understand IO monads (following [Functional Programming in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)), and managed to write some erroneous code that somehow passed the compilation and caused me some headache.

In the below example, I am writing a stack-safe *interpreter* of an *IO monad*. The code is in the pattern matching on a polymorphic Algebraic Data Type (`FlatMap[A, B]`). The error in the code is `k1 andThen k2`; the two functions can't compose because `k1` is returning a different type (`IO[B]`) than what `k2` expects (`B`). **The code still type-checks somehow**, and it is obviously a typechecking error because, in the runtime, there is a `ClassCastException` at an automatic unboxing (just as if I was using an unsafe cast in Java). There are also no compiler warnings issued.

The code (also found on [gist](https://gist.github.com/zsolt-donca/b1c5ec97e265ff691f962efe0792235b)):

```
  object IOMonadExercise extends App {

  sealed trait IO[A]    
  case class Return[A](value: A) extends IO[A]    
  case class Suspend[A](f: () => A) extends IO[A]    
  case class FlatMap[A, B](io: IO[A], cont: A => IO[B]) extends IO[B]

  object IO {
    def apply[A](a: => A): IO[A] = Suspend(() => a)
  }

  object Interpreter {
    def run[A](io: IO[A]): A = {
      io match {
        case Return(a) => a
        case Suspend(f) => f()

        case FlatMap(Return(a), cont) => run(cont(a))
        case FlatMap(Suspend(f), cont) => run(cont(f()))

        // this case compiles for whatever reason but shouldn't type check (k1 returns IO[B] and k2 expects just B)
        // accordingly, there is a ClassCastException in the runtime
        case FlatMap(FlatMap(io1, k1), k2) => run(FlatMap(io1, k1 andThen k2))

        // this case is the one that actually works
//        case FlatMap(FlatMap(io1, k1), k2) => run(flatten(io1, k1, k2))
      }
    }

    def flatten[A, B, C](io: IO[A], k1: A => IO[B], k2: B => IO[C]): FlatMap[A, C] = {
      FlatMap(io, a => FlatMap(k1(a), k2))
    }
  }


  def sum(i: Int): IO[Int] = {
    Stream.range(0, i).foldLeft(IO(0))((io, i) => FlatMap(io, (s: Int) => IO(s + i)))
  }

  val n = 100000
  val sumNIO: IO[Int] = sum(n)
  val sumN: Int = Interpreter.run(sumNIO)
  println(s"sum of 1..$n by IO loop  : $sumN")
  println(s"sum of 1..$n by math expr: ${n * (n - 1) / 2}")
  assert(sumN == n * (n - 1) / 2)
}
```

What is going on? Is this a compiler bug? Or is this a known limitation of the type inference? Or is there an explanation for this?

I've tested on both Scala 2.11.8 and on 2.12.0, and the behavior seems to be the same: the code compiles without warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a case of the [SI-5195](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5195) bug. If you construct the nested `FlatMap` manually, you cannot write that `andThen`, because all the types are known and `k1` and `k2` are obviously not composable.

But in that pattern matching types of `io1`, `k1` and `k2` are not known in advance, they have to be inferred and as we see they are inferred wrong. [...]

**EDIT**
Here is another try to explain how it type-checks: if you start inferring types for `k1` and `k2` yourself, you will come up with

- `k1: X => IO[Y]` and `k2: Y => IO[A]` for some `X` and `Y`
- plus from `k1 andThen k2` you need `IO[Y] <: Y`

So does there exist any type `Y` which satisfies these restrictions? Yes, it's `Any`. 
But when you apply it, `IO[Y]` becomes `Suspend[Int]` and `Y` is just `Int` for which subtype relation doesn't hold.

Comment: It indeed looks like that! After some research in this direction, I've also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359696/scala-pattern-match-infers-any-instead-of-an-existential-type-breaks-type-saf

And also this issue, which seems to be related to SI-5195: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6680